# How to load a script only for certain country in blogger?

Tags: javascript, blogger

I have a script which I want to load only for a certain country in blogger, how can I do that?

I tried doing something like

```
<script>
if (url contains .com) {
    <script src=""></script>
}
</script>
```

but it's not working because nesting of the script is failing, the first `</script>` tag closes the outer `<script>` as well.

Comment: Why do you think you need the nested/inner `script` tags? It's everything _inside_ the `script` tags that you want to execute, so just remove the inner `script` tags ... you are already in "JavaScript mode"?

Comment: Actually it tries to load another script, you can see that src points to some host. How would you load a script without <script> tag?

Comment: The real issue is to find out the country of the visitor. Checking if your own (!) domain ends with .com will always have the same result for every visitor. Also, .com is not a country-specific TLD. You will need to check the visitor's IP address instead.

Comment: @paolo For default blogger addresses (not using a custom domain) the TLD changes according to where the user is accessing the site from. It's approximate. (Not sure where the `.com` refers to though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this,

```
<script>
if (url.indexOf(".com") > -1) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "you/script/url";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
</script>
```